# tuples in tuples - python wsdl reply

Tags: python, wsdl, python-2.5

I have reply like this:

```
(Result){
   rows[] =
      (ResultRow){
         param1 = "value1"
         values[] =
            (ResultValue){
               paramx1 = "valuex1"
               paramx2 = "valuex2"
               paramx3 = "valuex3"
               paramx4 = "valuex4"
               paramx5 = "valuex5"
            },
      },
   rownum = 1
 }
```

when I want print value `param1` I do this:

```
for row in reply.rows:
    print row.param1
```

but I don't know how to print value `paramx1` from tuple `values[]`

Comment: I don't really know about wsdl, but it appears as if you just need to go deeper i.e. print reply.rows.values[0] or something like that. sorry if that's not right, but I think it's along the right lines